# How can I share static files with Blazor.Server, Blazor.WebAssebly and Blazor.Components?

Tags: css, .net, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

I have a Blazor Solution with Blazor.Server, Blazor.WebAssebly and Blazor.Components projects using .Net6.

If it is posible i like to share common static files with the different projects. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of files?

Comment: source files like css and js. The wwwroot folder